# Adding a subdomain backed by an alb to route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have mapped a godaddy domain to an AWS instance by creating and ALB and adding it to Route53. I have purchased an SSL from Godaddy and installed the same on ALB.

I am now trying to add a subdomain to the same configuration wherein the sub-domain will be mapped to another EC2 instance. I am new to this setup and the way I understand is, there are two ways I can do that:
1. Create a record in the hosted zone and map it to the subdomain.
2. Create a hosted zone and add it as an NS record to the hosted zone of the parent domain.

Now I want to know if I can:
1. Attach a load balancer to the other instance and add it as a subdomain. If yes, then how?
2. Add the other instance to the existing load balancer and configure routing for it then add a record in the hosted zone with the load balancer as an alias.

The instances in the discussion would act as a frontend and a backend respectively. 
Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Route 53 records should be added for your hosted zone (parent domain):

```
example.com.            A   ALIAS your-aws-alb-alias
subdomain.example.com.  A   ALIAS your-aws-alb-alias
```

You don't need to create another hosted zone for subdomain.

Then you can add instances to ALB through Target Groups. See [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html).

Create target groups for backend and frontend, for example *Backend-Target* and *Frontend-Target*. Then you need to create host-based rules in ALB. For example:

```
IF Host is subdomain.example.com THEN Forward to Backend-Target: 1 (100%)
IF Host is example.com THEN Forward to Frontend-Target: 1 (100%)
```

The order of the rules matters. Rules in ALB are processed from top to bottom.

Comment: Hi @vlad-chikov, thank you for your response, it answers most of my question, but, I have done as you've said and added an A record to route53 and then created a target group mapping to the other instance. Now, when attaching the same to the load balancer, I am presented with two listeners, 443 and 80. To which listener should I add the new rule and attach the other target group?  And after adding rules to 443 listener, the health check for targe group has failed with 302 response. Thanks.!

Comment: It depends of your purposes. You can redirect port 80 to 443 'Redirect tohttps://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query} Status code:HTTP_301;' And create all rules for port 443.

Comment: @vamshikrishnaAnandesi you can create healthcheck for target group on port 80.

Comment: Hi, the second instance in discussion runs on port 80 and I have modified it apache config file to redirect all requests from http to https with the following piece of code:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
Now, when I am trying to create a routing policy by editing the listeners on port 443, the status check for the instance is failing with code 302, and when I am accessing the subdomain in the browser, I am getting a 'This connection is not private' message.

Comment: In ALB create one rule for HTTP:80 listener to HTTPS redirect (redirecting to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query})  Add instances to target groups (with 80 and 443 ports).  Create health checks of target groups on HTTP protocol.  
Your webserver should listen 80 and 443 ports, no need redirection to HTTPS on webserver side.

Comment: Hi, can I follow this link to do what you've suggested: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/. Also, the default rule for http:80 is mapped to the first target group which is mapped to my frontend. What should be added in the condition, if I were to create a rule on http:80 listener? However, although this hasn't completely solved my issue, it got me a lot closer to it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @vamshikrishnaAnandesi, for more correct recommendations it's necessary to know whole architecture. I hope that my information will help you move in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution did help me a lot!

Comment: Hi, @Vlad, I think your solution was apt, cause I've come to learn that the standard Godaddy SSL I've bought doesn't cover subdomains. So if I get that sorted out, I might be able to get it to work. Thank you again for your support.!